# How to pass the query on the interceptor on angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

Is there any way to pass a query and params on the interceptor in angular 8

```js
    const params = new HttpParams()
            .set('lang', localStorage.getItem('language'))
            .set('android_version', '1')
```

Comment: can you share what you did yet or what you trying to do

Comment: or you can tell me use case of passing data to interceptor

Comment: Iam trying to pass the lang query on the interceptor. But lang is passing as the params. I need to pass as the lang as the query

Comment: I need to pass the lang as query 

eg :"?lang=en&android_version=1"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify the request by using  [`HttpRequest#clone`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#clone) method.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const newReq = req.clone({
      params: (req.params ? req.params : new HttpParams())
                 .set('lang', localStorage.getItem('language')) /*.... add new params here .....*/ 
    });

    return next.handle(newReq);
  }
}
```

Refer : https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability

Comment: I need to pass both queries
now also lang is passing as the query


.set('lang', localStorage.getItem('language'))
        .set('android_version', '1')

Comment: cannot find name 'http' @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @viveka : that's request object

Comment: I need to pass the lang as query 

eg :"?lang=en&android_version=1"

Comment: @viveka :  `const newReq = req.clone({
      url: req.url +  "?lang=en&android_version=1" 
    });`

Comment: @viveka : if in some case there is an existing query param, then you have to do it like : `const newReq = req.clone({ url: req.url + (req.url.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + "lang=en&android_version=1" });`